# Is there any tools for writing the test cases automatically in iPhone and Blackberry mobile applications?

Tags: iphone, testing, blackberry

Any one can suggest me is there any tools writing the test cases automatically in iPhone and Blackberry applications just like "Monkey Runner" in Android applications.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hey.
It will be hard to find one tool for different platforms (BlackBerry+iPhone+Andorid+....).
One that I am aware of is [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/mobile-application-testing-smart-devices.html), but it is commercial product - I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen actual unit testing framework for blackberry.

I have used a while ago some j2me based framework but if you want to test you have to start the simulator.

Here you might find somethin useful:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Unit-Testing/m-p/22592